# How to remove square[ ] brackets from value in SoapUI?

Tags: rest, api, soapui

In SoapUI I'm trying to pass the response header value of Request1 as a header value for Request2 header.

I'm able to fetch the required value from Request1 response header.
But, it's fetched in a [ ] rather as a string.

```
def value = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["GetToken"].testRequest.response.responseHeaders["Authorization"]
def tc = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName("JTY")
tc.setPropertyValue("csrf", "$value")
```

Expected:  csrf = `fetched value`

Actual:  csrf = `[fetched value]`

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI insists on returning most things as an array.

```
tc.setPropertyValue("csrf", value[0])
```

should work.